# How to filter by status information column in Thruk

Tags: monitoring, filter, settings

I am using Thruk as a monitoring interface. At the top left corner of the page there is a button which opens a stack with filters of which hosts/services etc. you want to apply.
You can easily add such filters as Host, Service, Duration, and so on.

But I have several services with different sets of descriptions in the Status Information column. I want to be able to only show interested set, but I cannot see a "Status Information" choise in the drop-down list in filters stack.

Is filtering by Status Information possible in Thruk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Just use a "**Plugin Output**" item in drop-down list in filters stack, and write the string you wish to filter by.

Also you can filter results by using "**Search**" filter. It searches string in all columns, not just in Status Information.